# Do I need to uninstall Xcode when upgrading?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Or do I just install the new one on top of the existing one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install it.

Answer (score 1):

[Stop overthinking things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215122/how-do-i-upgrade-iphone-sdk-from-3-1-2-to-3-1-3). In virtually every case - definitely every Apple-provided case - if an app needs to be uninstalled before a new version is installed, it will warn you, and likely prevent you from continuing until you do so.